# IronPython doesn't recognize win32com

Tags: python, ironpython, win32com

I need to run a software through IronPython ( I have to and can only use Ironpython and it's not a choice) . this software needs win32com library to be loaded so the software could be run. But Importing it in IronPython fails since it's not a recognized library.
I tried to load win32com library in python and then try to run the software, and it was successful. But now the problem is that I need to run this python file through Ironpython, I mentioned the python name via :

```
os.system("pythontry.py 1")
```

It sounds like something has worked, cause I don't get the error win32com is not a recognized module, but from the other side, nothing happens . I mean that software does not run

Comment: I would expect this command to run "pythontry.py" as a separate process, using the system default Python interpreter; so probably not IronPython.

Comment: IronPython is not a choice , I have to use it, and The third software could be run, if I could call the python code from IronPython. So if it does not work, I should find another command, but the connection route starts from IronPython

Comment: You already mentioned you don't have any choice. I believe @alexis's point was simply that the `os.system("pythontry.py 1")` probably **isn't** running the script with IronPython.

Comment: Ok great, as I guessed, so is there an alternative you could add?